# Javascript convert picture bytes to hex

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, binary, hex

I've tried to convert a local image file to string via canvas

```
imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

But it only returns a Base64 encoded string.

Is there any way to convert the image binary into a hex **string** like

```
0x310000700008000400efbeee3a851a54...
```

Yet like what function `unpack('H*')` does in perl/ruby.

Comment: what's wrong with the b64 string? What happens if you decode it? Won't that give you the binary?

Comment: I think he might mean he want such a function like `pack`/`unpack` in perl or something.

Answer (score 0):

http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_decode/ ... a JavaScript function analog to `base64_decode` ... there is a jQuery plugin for that http://hpyer.cn/codes/jquery-plugin-base64-encode-and-decode

Answer (score 0):

This is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

In JavaScript there are two functions respectively for decoding and encoding base64 strings:

[atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.atob)

[btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.btoa)

```
var encodedData = window.btoa("Hello, world"); // encode a string

var decodedData = window.atob(encodedData); // decode the string

encodedData = window.btoa("011110000100101"); //RESULT is "MDExMTEwMDAwMTAwMTAx"
```

**OR (in node.js)**

```
fs = require('fs');
imgBuffer = fs.readFileSync('public/images/my_image_location.gif');
imgHex = imgBuffer.toString('hex');
console.log(imgHex)
```